# How to create a .java file using java?

Tags: java

I want to create a .java file but I'm doing something wrong as when I try to create it, I simply get a directory named example.java.

What I want to do is actually create a file with the extension `.java`

This is the snippet of my code which isn't working as wished:

`new File(src, name + ".java").mkdir();`

How can I implement as described above?

Comment: `mkdir` means "make directory".

Comment: `File#mkdir` method is similar to the `mkdir` command in Windows and Unix/Linux: makes a dir.

Comment: Consider to use the new NIO.2 API: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileio.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createFile%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...%29

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`File` is just an abstract representation of your file. Create a `new File` object won't create it for "real"

You have to call the method [`createNewFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createNewFile%28%29) on it :

```
File f = new File(src, name + ".java");
if(!f.exists())//check if the file already exists
    f.createNewFile();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
new File(src, name + ".java").createNewFile();
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`createNewFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createNewFile%28%29) instead of `mkdir`.

[`mkdir`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdir%28%29) as the name implies will create a directory.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new file with the new NIO.2 API (recommended if you're using Java SE 7 or greater):

```
Path javaFilePath = Paths.get(src, name + ".java");
if (! Files.exists(javaFilePath)){
    Files.createFile(javaFilePath);
}
```

Tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html#creating

Javadoc:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html